How do I find detail about failed scheduled extracts?
I am looking for all failures for scheduled extracts. They are not included in the regular LookStudio log files and according to other articles I have found, I need BigQuery Cloud Logging access to protoPayload.serviceName="bigquerybiengine.googleapis.com" and protoPayload.serviceName="bigquery.googleapis.com", but it is unclear what access I need added to get that.  I am a BigQuery Admin in our account but those events do not appear to be captured when they are coming from LookerStudio scheduled jobs. Isn't there some central logging console for LookerStudio in either console.google.com or admin.google.com?
I have tried searching documentation and the forum and most if not all the forum posts are closed out with unhelpful links.

I think of Looker Studio as a free BI tool.  Your post talks about "extracts" ... do you perhaps mean queries?  Can you elaborate on what you mean by extracts?   How do you know something is failing?   Reading here ... https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control ... it seems that to view Cloud Logging logs you need the "Logs Viewer" role.   If something is failing in the query ... I would expect to see BigQuery records being written to the log.

@Kolban In LookerStudio Pro(should have included that in OP) there is a feature to schedule extracts and store the results to avoid repeat calls and also optimize result set performance for reports.  More about the feature can be found here link These events do not show up in the normal LookerStudio logs. These scheduled 'extracts' fail as indicated by a red 'x' for 'Status' in the studio UI after you drill into the report in edit mode with no detail. Trying to find that event.
